# Optimize the order of styles and scripts

Tags: javascript, css

How to resolve "Optimize the order of styles and scripts" ---  5 inline script blocks were found in the head between an external CSS file and another resource. To allow parallel downloading, move the inline script before the external CSS file, or after the next resource.

while loading the external JavaScript dynamically it was blocking some inline scripts from the same external script, so how to identify this.

Comment: Is there any particular platform or framework on which you are working?

Comment: Why does it sound like you have copied/pasted a bug report?

Comment: I can face this issue when i am doing "Web page Performance" on chrome browase. This is due to css and inline script and external script are used on HEAD part